# Transforming a Query for JDATABASE

Tags: php, mysql, jdatabase

I need to transform a simple php query into a query that `JDATABASE` will understand.

Here is the example:

```
$resDays        = 7;                // On how many days to build the top?
$resLimit       = 20;               // How many results to display?

$query = "SELECT `artist`, title, count(*) AS tracks FROM `history
          WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `date_played`, NOW()) <= " . $resDays . "
          AND `song_type`=0 GROUP BY title ORDER BY tracks DESC LIMIT 0," . $resLimit;
```

And this is what I managed to do:

```
// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('artist', 'title')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('history'));

$db->setQuery($query);
$query->setLimit(20);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
```

The problem is that I don't know how to include in my query the missing parts like `ORDER tracks` or `count(*) AS tracks`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('artist', 'title')));
$query->select('COUNT(*) AS tracks');
$query->from($db->quoteName('history'));
$query->where('TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date_played, NOW()) <= ' . $db->quote($resDays));
$query->where('song_type = 0');
$query->group('title');
$query->order('tracks DESC');

// Set the query + limit
$db->setQuery($query, 0, $resLimit);
```

You can test how your query looks like with $query->dump();

API: https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQuery.html

Comment: Just a note. If you're using Joomla 3.x, you use `->setLimit(20);` rather than defining it in `setQuery`

Comment: Setting limit (and offset) with setQuery saves one method call plus ->setLimit() is nowhere used by the core (only in a test case). I don't see an advantage by using that method though it's surely an alternative

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` can be achieved using `->group(...)` and the `ORDER BY` can be achieved using `->order(...)`.

So your full query would look like this:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
      ->select(
          array(
            $db->quoteName('artist'),
            $db->quoteName('title'),
            'COUNT(*) AS ' . $db->quoteName('tracks')
          )
      )
      ->from($db->quoteName('history'))
      ->where('TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, ' . $db->quoteName('date_played') . ', NOW()) <= ' . $db->quote($resDays))
      ->where($db->quoteName('song_type') . ' = 0')
      ->group($db->quoteName('title'))
      ->order($db->quoteName('tracks') . ' DESC')
      ->setLimit(20);

$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadObjectList();
```

I am not entirely 100% sure about the `where` clause that I've written for you. Have a test and let me know if it works.

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function group() on a non-object in   ->group($db->quoteName('title'))`

Comment: But, thank's for explaining me how to use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`, and you code that youve writen to me i will use in next query that i need.

Comment: How about [where() with glue](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQuery.html#method_where) or [andWhere()](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQuery.html#method_andWhere) ?

Comment: @mickmackusa - Good shout. Probably answered before I knew about the default `and` glue. Updated the answer

Comment: ...a couple more mentions: you can chain from `getQuery` and I can't think of any advantage to casting `(int)` on a static `0`.  To improve researcher confidence please remove your post-code-block disclaimer -- because you _know_ that it's good now.

Comment: Is there any hope of prepared statements with placeholders in the near future in Joomla? I want a `bind()` method asap!

Comment: @mickmackusa - Updated again. Keeping the small disclaimer as I hadn't actually tested the code for this specific scenario. It was the first `where` clause I was unsure about. As for the prepared statements, I'd suggest asking on the Joomla Github Issue Tracker and tagging `mbabker`, as he maintains the database framework package ;)